# Sharepoint 2010 Web Services: UserProfileService: Access denied

Tags: web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am tryng to get count of user profiles via UserProfileService web serivce (Sharepoint Server 2010), but for all users(except sharepoint system acount) returned

> Operation Failure ---> Access Denied: Only an administrator may
>   retrieve a count of all users.

With sharepoint system acount (say 'domain\megauser') it is work as expected.

I try add other users to farm administrators group, site collection administrators group, but it did not help - same error.

Can I give even more rights for user(more than farm administrator)? Or UserProfileService require some special permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the other users to the UserProfileService Application:

1. Go to the Central Application - Manage Service Applications
2. Click the User Profile Service Application (highlight it)
3. Open Service Application Tab and click Permissions
4. Add the users with the given permissions (i.e. Full Control)